# Yii2 saving file to Oracle BLOB

Tags: php, oracle, yii2, blob

Problem is that i can't save file to blob. It works without any error, temp file is created and i can read from it. I checked if it goes to bind - yes it goes with right resource value and with `\PDO::PARAM_LOB` data type.

I have an ActiveRecord class:

```
class News extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [
                ['image'],
                'image',
                'extensions' => 'png jpg',
                'maxSize' => 1024 * 300,
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        $fileInfo = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image');
        $this->image = fopen($fileInfo->tempName, 'r+');
        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }

}
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE NEWS
(
    RN NUMBER(17,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    IMAGE BLOB
);
```

Logs showing this query:

```
INSERT INTO "NEWS" ("IMAGE") VALUES (:qp4) RETURNING "RN" INTO :qp8
```

So it didn't actually bind it or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that PDO_OCI is working with Oracle in old-style way, so you need to start a transaction insert `EMPTY_BLOB()` first, then bind variable with pointer to file, execute statement and commit.

I've done it with update,  because i don't want to make full query manually. First i write pointer to file into `$this->file` in `save()` method and call `$model->save && $model->saveImage()` in controller.

```
public function saveImage()
{
    if (!$this->file) {
        return true;
    }
    $table = self::tableName();
    $rn = $this->rn;
    $command = Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand(
        "UPDATE $table SET IMAGE=EMPTY_BLOB() WHERE RN=:rn RETURNING IMAGE INTO :image"
    );
    $command->bindParam(':rn', $rn, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $command->prepare();
    $command->bindParam(':image', $this->file, \PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    return $command->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should simply use image data instead of resource pointer, e.g. :

```
$this->image = file_get_contents($fileInfo->tempName);
```

EDIT: sorry you are right, you need to provide a resource pointer to be able to bind this param using `PARAM_LOB`.

As stated on [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php#example-983), you should try using a [transaction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#transactional-operations), e.g. :

```
News::getDb()->transaction(function($db) use ($model) {
    $model->save();
});
```

Comment: It gives me ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Comment: Judging by `UploadedFile` source code - there's no reason for this to work. And, well, it gives ORA-01465: invalid hex number

Comment: It is a transaction for me.

Comment: You mean you are already using a transaction ? Show us your controller code. And did you try to use `rb` instead of `r+` with `fopen()` ?

Comment: It was started on other level, not in controller, system is complicated, but it surely starts. I will try 'rb' now.